# Pointer to a structure losing data from the original structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to create a structure that stores different values and reference them via a pointer, and use that pointer within a function, but once i pass the pointer to a function it seems to lose all the data that was within the original structure the pointer was pointing too.

this is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #pragma warning(disable:4996)

     void clear_screen();
     void stopE();
     void cost(struct coffee *cust1);
     void reciept(char name[], int coff, int tea, double total, double noTax);
     double noTax(struct coffee *cust1);
    struct coffee
    {
        char name[21];
        int cCups;
        int tCups;
        double totalCost;
    };

    void main()
    {
        char buffer[10] = {0};
        struct coffee cust;

        printf("Please input the customers name: ");
        gets(cust.name);
        printf(" \nPlease enter how many cups of coffee ordered: ");
        gets(buffer);
        cust.cCups = atoi(buffer);
        stopE();
        printf(" \nPlease enter how many cups of tea ordered: ");
        gets(buffer);
        cust.tCups = atoi(buffer);
        stopE();
        struct coffee *cust1 = &cust;


        clear_screen();
        double withoutTax = noTax(&cust1);
        cost(&cust1);
        reciept(cust.name, cust.cCups, cust.tCups, cust.totalCost, withoutTax);


    }

    void stopE()
    {
        int c = getchar();
        while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        {
            c = getchar();
        }
    }
    void cost(struct coffee *cust1)
    {
        double a = (double)cust1->cCups*1.75;
        double b = (double)cust1->tCups * 1.5;

        double inter = a + b;
        double totalCost = inter + (inter*0.13);
        cust1->totalCost = totalCost;
    }
    double noTax(struct coffee *cust1)
    {
        double totalCost = (cust1->cCups*1.75) + (cust1->tCups*1.5);
        return totalCost;
    }
    void reciept(char name[], int coff, int tea, double total, double noTax)
    {
        printf("Coffee Co.\n");
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = rand() % 101;
        printf("Order Number: %d\n", r);
        printf("Name: %s\n", name);

        for (int i = 0; i < coff; i++)
        {
            printf("Coffee:            $1.75\n");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tea; i++)
        {
            printf("Tea:               $1.50\n");
        }
        printf("Total without tax: $%.2f", noTax);
        printf("\n13%% Tax total:     $%.2f", (noTax*0.13));
        p

rintf("\nTotal:             $%.2f\n", total);
    getchar();

}
void clear_screen(void)//Function to clear screen 
{
    DWORD n;                         /* Number of characters written */
    DWORD size;                      /* number of visible characters */
    COORD coord = { 0 };               /* Top left screen position */
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    /* Get a handle to the console */
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, &csbi);

    /* Find the number of characters to overwrite */
    size = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

    /* Overwrite the screen buffer with whitespace */
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(h, TEXT(' '), size, coord, &n);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(h, csbi.wAttributes, size, coord, &n);

    /* Reset the cursor to the top left position */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, coord);
}
```

if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated, I cannot figure out how to get the data to pass to the function.

EDIT: The pragma is to remove the error with scanf that prevents me from running my program because it isnt secure.

Comment: `double withoutTax = noTax(&cust1);` --> `double withoutTax = noTax(cust1);`, you don't need to pass the address because `cust1` is already a pointer.

Comment: What warnings do you get from your compiler?  Fix them!  Esp. the ones that look like `'coffee *' differs in levels of indirection from 'coffee **'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

`struct coffee *cust1 = &cust;`

is unnecessary. I see that when you're passing this pointer to your pricing functions, you do so with

`double withoutTax = noTax(&cust1); cost(&cust1);`

This is passing the address of (&) the pointer cust1 to the function. What you want to do is pass either just the pointer, or more simply the address of the original struct.

`double withoutTax = noTax(cust1); cost(cust1);` or

`double withoutTax = noTax(&cust); cost(&cust);`

I tested the program in an online IDE and it seemed to function properly with this change.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying too hard:

Replace:

```
struct coffee *cust1 = &cust;

clear_screen();
double withoutTax = noTax(&cust1);
cost(&cust1);
```

by:

```
clear_screen();
double withoutTax = noTax(&cust);
cost(&cust);
```

`&cust` is the address of `cust` or in other words: it's the pointer to `curst`.

Didn't you get compiler warnings ?